# Sensitive word search with powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I am somewhat new to PowerShell so any help I would appreciate.
I am trying to put a PS script together so that I can search a file for sensitive words before transferring it from one network to another.  Like 'Classified' and multiple other words that I can add to a word bank in a text file vice updating the code every time

Right now I am forced to use PS 2 windows 7 and server 2008

```
Select-String -Path e:\transfer_folder\*.* -pattern Classified,restricted
```

Then I can get an output for any hits on the list of words so that I can find them.  I am trying to speed up my searching through hundreds of pages of documents with what I like to call a dirty word search so I do not put something that should not go on the wrong network.

Comment: Why script this, when Windows proper provides a enterprise service specifically for this. Look at the FSRM/FCI documentation.  --- http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/D/3/DD3FB42C-D3C7-47C0-9431-40D80256FB0A/FCI_TDM_WP_May_09.pdf --- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/solution-guides/deploy-automatic-file-classification--demonstration-steps-  ---https://www.rootusers.com/configure-file-classification-infrastructure-fci-using-fsrm/  ---

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea. The `-Pattern` tack in powershell can usually be called on to work with regular expressions. If you've never worked with regular expressions, take a look at this [beginner's guide to using regex pattern matching](https://regexone.com/). What you probably want is a set of variables that you can use to dynamically pick out those sensitive keywords.

The short and simple answer is that you want to use a pipe to separate your options for pattern, and pass it in as a string.

`Select-String -Path e:\transfer_folder\*.* -pattern "Classified|Restricted"`

Also, you might want to think about doing this at the file level rather than just importing all of your stuff in willynilly like that. I would go for something like:

`$files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path E:\transfer_folder\ -Filter "*.txt|*.etc").FullName`

(The `@` symbol means that you get your output as an array. The `.FullName` means that you're only selecting the FullName field from the object that's being produced by the command.)

Then you can process each file individually, like:

```
Foreach ($file in $files) {
   Write-Host "Processing $file"
   echo (Select-String -Path $file -Pattern $pattern) 
}
```

One of the reasons that I love powershell is how comparatively easy it is to perform these types of matching operations. If you dig into Regex, you'll notice that you can represent "OR" as "|". So you have two options to do this logically:

1. Just hard write it out

`$pattern = "Classified|Forbidden|Death|Danger"`

2. Do it dynamically

Scripting is all about not having to do things more than once, right? So you'll probably want to encapsulate this in a function or something. Or maybe you want to get your words from a text file? You can be like:
(might take some tweaking)

```
function Get-ForbiddenWords ([string[]]$words, [string]$folder) {
   ForEach ($word in $words) {
      $pattern += "$word|" 
    }
    #remove trailing pipe
    $pattern -replace ".$"
    $files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Filter "*.txt|*.etc").FullName
    Foreach ($file in $files) {
       Write-Host "Processing $file"
       echo (Select-String -Path $file -Pattern $pattern) 
    }
}
```

Now you can put this in your powershell profile and invoke it with

`Get-ForbiddenWords -words secret dangerous whatever -folder E:\transfer_folder\`